# Unique Combined Values Of Two Columns SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQL is there a way that you can tell the database not to allow repeated values of a combination of two columns? Similar to how we use unique id's that cant be repeated.

For example.

[image]

Though the first names repeated in the first four,
and the last names repeated, the error didn't throw until the combination was repeated.

I am using sqlite at the moment.

Comment: Pretty sure you have a composite primary key or composite unique constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
( 
  .
  .
  .
  last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR,
  CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (last_name, first_name)
);
```